# Reduce space in between subplots containing choropleth maps

Tags: r, choropleth

I am trying to generate a figure containing six choropleth maps in R. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
library(rgdal)
library(GISTools)

# code that loads data needed to generate choropleth maps not shown

par(mfrow = c(3,2), mar=c(0,0,0,0), oma=c(0,6,6,0))


choropleth(mn_county, mn_county$emppct.tert.2006, shades) 
mtext( 'Secondary', side=3, line=2)
mtext( '1998', side=2, line=2)

choropleth(mn_county, mn_county$emppct.tert.2006, shades) 
# choropleth maps are repeated in this post for simplicity
mtext( 'Tertiary', side=3, line=2)

choropleth(mn_county, mn_county$emppct.tert.2006, shades)
mtext( '2006', side=2, line=2)

choropleth(mn_county, mn_county$emppct.tert.2006, shades)
choropleth(mn_county, mn_county$emppct.tert.2006, shades)
mtext( '2014', side=2, line=2)

choropleth(mn_county, mn_county$emppct.tert.2006, shades)
```

The problem is, even though I set margins `mar` to be zero throughout, there are still big gaps between the columns (see below). Not just between the choropleth maps, but also between the row headings (1998, 2006, 2014) and the maps.

How can I reduce this wide space?

[image]

Comment: ```shades``` and ```mn_county``` objects are missing in your code example.  But have you tried to change the window size?  It looks as if your window is simply too wide.

Comment: I just re-posted the question on the GIS stackexchange, and yes, it is due to the window sizing.